# Possibility Problem

Tags: probability

A man has a $20$% chance of hitting a target, with all attempts being independent
of each other. If he shoots at a target $10$ times, what is the probability he will hit the
target at least once?

I am very new at Math. My idea is just $20$% cause it counts independently.

Comment: 20% would only be correct if hitting with different shots was perfectly correlated.  For example, if each shot went exactly where the previous shot went, but there is only a 20% chance that that repeated result is aimed at the target.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probability to hit target at-least once : $1 - (\text{probability to hit target zero times}.)$

Probability of hitting, $p=0.2$

Probability of not hitting, $1-p=0.8$

So answer would be: $$1 - (1-p)^{10}=1-0.8^{10}=1-0.1074=0.8926$$

Answer (score 1):

You say your idea is $20%$ because it counts independently. Here's why that fails. Imagine a man that shoots at the target one million times, not only $10$ times. Using your logic, he still has a $20%$ chance of hitting the target, even if he shot one billion times? If you throw one die, the probability of it being $6$ is $1/6$. If you throw the die a million times, you are (intuitively) almost sure that at least one of the throws will end in a $6$.

For example, if the man shoots $2$ times, what is the chance of him missing both? The chance of him missing the first is $80$%$=0.8$. The probability of him missing the second is the same. The shots are independent, meaning the probability of him missing both is $0.8\cdot 0.8 = 0.64$!